# what all are symbols not supported by Watson service to avoid BadRequestException

Tags: java, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, watson

I am currently using IBM Watson's text-to-speech API, by Java SDK

Code as follows

```
TextToSpeech textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech();
textToSpeech.setUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
ServiceCall<InputStream> inputStreamServiceCall = textToSpeech.synthesize(text, Voice.EN_ALLISON, AudioFormat.OGG);
InputStream in = inputStreamServiceCall.execute();
```

While converting text to speech getting following exception

> com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.BadRequestException:
>           at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:416)
>   ~[java-sdk-3.3.0.jar:na]
>           at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$1.execute(WatsonService.java:179)
>   ~[java-sdk-3.3.0.jar:na]
>
> com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService
>   processServiceCall SEVERE: GET
>   https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?text=Question%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20Use%20the%20figure%20below%20to%20answer%20the%20following%20question.%20If%20AC||DE,%20which%20of%20the%20following%20justifies%20%CE%94ABC%20~%20%CE%94DBE?%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20Answer%20Choices%20%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20Choice%20A%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20%20Definition%20of%20Similar%20Triangles%20%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20Choice%20B%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20%20SAS%20Similarity%20Theorem%20%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20Choice%20C%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20%20SSS%20Similarity%20Theorem%20%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20Choice%20D%20%20%3Cbreak%20time%3D%221s%22/%3E%20%20%20AA%20Similarity%20Postulate%20&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&accept=audio/ogg;%20codecs%3Dopus,
>   status: 400, error:

I have solved this issue by replacing following symbols “”©—’‘▒ "{}|`\​ with space.

please suggest what all are symbols not supported by watson service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrade your com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud java-sdk to higher version.latest is 3.8.0. in java-sdk-3.3.0.jar some of the characters are not getting encoded properly while making API calls to watson.